# toggle link value by click

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to change value of a link and functionality when I click it.

```
<li><a href="#" class="headProjects">Projects</a></li>
```

Toggle Class doesn't fit because there are lots of actions with DOM after click, which I don't need to toggle.

When I click first time it works.

```
$('.headProjects').click(() => {
    $('.headProjects').text('home')
   $('.headProjects').removeClass('headProjects').addClass('homePage')
  })
```

Class changes as written above.
When I try to click element with new class 'homePage' it doesn't see this item or/and simultaneously runs functions from first click.

```
$('.homePage').click(() => {
    $('.homePage').text('Projects')
$('.homePage').removeClass('homePage').addClass('headProjects')
  })
```

No errors in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to dynamically bind the click event as when you attach click event handler with class `headProject` that time `homePage` does not exist and hence click event handler does not get binded.
See below solution

```js
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.headProjects', function(){
    $(this).text('home'); // change text of clicked element only
  $(this).removeClass('headProjects').addClass('homePage')
});
$(document).on('click','.homePage', function(){
    $(this).text('Projects'); // change text of clicked element only
  $(this).removeClass('homePage').addClass('headProjects');
});
});
```

```css
.headProjects {
  color: green;
}
.homePage {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="headProjects">Projects</a></li>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)